# How to run nodejs and docker-compose.yml in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Nodejs app that requires connection with two containers in a `docker-compose.yml` file via a `credentials.json`. I can run `docker-compose run` and start my app without problem in my local IDE. However, I would like to deploy it in Elastic Beanstalk. Can someone please help with an instruction? The app structure folder looks similar to this.

```
docker-compose.yml 
nodejsApp.js
package.json
credentialsFile.json
```

Comment: I would suggest trying to run the images in your docker compose on the EB Docker platform.

Comment: Can I add the list of steps to deploy a docker container to AWS EB ? But is that you are looking for